# how to rewrite the css rule without the element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use a plugin call http://www.skitter-slider.net/  with jquery

and I meet a problem:

I want to rewrite the default img css style:

```
.box_skitter .box_clone img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20;

}
```

but I can't rewrite by the element class, id, etc..

```
 $('.box_skitter .box_clone img').css({'width':w+'px','height':h+'px'});
```

because the plugin will create the img element dynamically, means It's no effect that I set the height, width for the element img

so what's the solution?

Comment: You need to apply the jquery after the creation of img element. Not in dom ready

Comment: Off-topic note: jQuery assumes pixels, you don't need to specify.

Comment: It has a `theme` option. You could probably use your own theme.

Answer (score 0):

I think I find a way to solve:

```
$('head').append('<style>.box_skitter .box_clone img{width:'+w+'px !important;}</style>');
```